# Xively and keypad.h

Tags: arduino-uno, xively

So I am making a basic "security" system using a PIR sensor and a keypad to disarm and arm. It is also updating Xively with the sensor readings using a Ethernet 2 shield. it will update with no problems when I do not have my `readKeypad()` code in it. As soon as I put in my code for the PIN entry it stops updating Xively giving me a can't connect error. Below is the basic code for keypad PIN entry, if I comment out the `keypad.getkey()` it will update, but with it in it does not work.

So I have it narrowed down to `keypad.getkey()` being the cause but I have no idea why. Anyone have this or a similar problem with Xively?

I have been trying different ways to read the keys and I tried to change `getKey()` to something else. I tried `getState()`, it will now update Xively but of course this doesn't return the key values I need. It would appear it does not like the `getKey()` command
I have also tried with thingspeak and it has the same problem.

```arduino
void readKeypad()
{
  char entry = keypad.getKey();
  Serial.print(entry);
  if (entry != NO_KEY)
  {
    attempt[z]=entry;
    z++;
    switch(entry)
    {
    case '#':
      z=0;
      delay(100); // for extra debounce
      checkPIN();
      break;
    }
  }
}
```